# openConnection get xml with UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, urlconnection

I want to download and save xml file using openConnection.

The problem is, that when i save file, there is wrong charset.

My code is:

```
URL url = new URL(partnersEntity.getUrl());

            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "500000");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");


            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date now = calendar.getTime();
            Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(now.getTime());

            File file = new File(myFile);

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

            IOUtils.copy(urlConnection.getInputStream(), writer);
            writer.close();
```

After that in my file i see marks like "??" in special charters place.

What should i change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a Reader/Writer in this situation, leave the xml as-is.

```
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

        IOUtils.copy(urlConnection.getInputStream(), out);
```

by using FileWriter, you are writing the xml data using the platform default charset, which is never what you want to do.  always treat xml as *binary data*, not *textual data*.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Check that the resource you are reading really is in UTF-8.  You requested using the 'Accept-Charset' but that does not guarantee.  However.  Let's assume that it is UTF-8.

(2) Specify the character set of the writer you are using. By using FileWriter, you get the 'default' character set of the environment you are running in ... might not be UTF-8.  Better to be specific using OutputStreamWriter.

```
OutputStream os = new OutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
```

(3) Tell the copy how to interpret the incoming stream:

```
IOUtils.copy(urlConnection.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Since he *gets* the data as a binary stream and just wants to write to a file, there's no use in involving a `Writer` or encoding at all: he should just write it as a stream (as @jtahlborns answer shows).

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Far more elegant to leave it as a byte stream.  Wish I had thought of that....  However, if you do want to process the characters (and there are some cases where you want to do that) the lesson here is to be explicit about the character encoding, and never use FileWriter.